# Should I flag if I am not sure if a question is opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am not sure if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361065/best-practices-to-deploy-docker-on-digitalocean-using-terraform) is opinion-based. Should I still flag so a moderator decides or are flags only for when you are certain, so not to make mods lose time?

My reasoning is that flagging can serve so someone else takes a look and make a more educated decision, but maybe it leads to flag spamming. What is the community convention about this?

Comment: Re: flag spamming, it's probably the least worry when the [close votes review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) has currently about 4.1K questions ...

Comment: @GinoMempin Not exactly, that guy is sure that the question is subjective

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderators don't evaluate "needs improvement" flags (the category that casts "recommend closure" votes on a question)—those are evaluated by close-vote reviewers in the corresponding review queue.

You should not, in general, cast flags of any type when you are unsure. However, since closure flags are reviewed by other community members and do not go into effect unless at least 3 people with close-vote privileges have cast a concurring vote, it's OK to have a *bit* lower bar on when you decide to raise those.

[That particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72361065) certainly needs to be closed. There are *several* reasons that apply, including:

- Belongs on Server Fault, because it is a system administrative question, not a programming one
- Needs more focus, because it is too broad and asks too many questions in one
- Primarily opinion-based, because its second question asks for a broad, open-ended list of "best practices" and admits to not even having a starting point.

Personally, I would prefer to close for "needs more focus", rather than "primarily opinion-based", because I think that provides a better description of the actual problem. It is, in my experience, somewhat common for the phrasing "best practice(s)" to trigger instinctive "opinion-based" closures. The only time that's really legitimate is when the question is *also* too broad/unfocused.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should never custom-flag questions *just* for needing to be closed. Only flag for moderator intervention in cases where the community can't handle the issue (such as in cases of suspected voting fraud or other user misconduct); in cases where a standard flag (such as opinion-based, off-topic, etc.) applies, you should use that instead, especially for questions that should be closed because then the community can review the flag in the close vote queue.

Even in cases like spam or Rude/Abusive posts, using a standard flag leads to faster and easier reviewing (plus the community can often handle even those alone, since posts that receive enough red flags from the community will be auto-deleted without moderators ever needing to review the flag).

To address the details of your question, if you're not sure if a particular question should be closed, you can ask in [SOCVR chat](https://socvr.org/) or on Meta.

In terms of the question you link to, it should definitely be closed. Questions about "best practices" are almost always a) opinion-based and b) based on an incorrect premise - "best practices" rarely, if ever, exist. [There are good practices in context, but there are no best practices.](https://context-driven-testing.com/)

Comment: Nitpicking: *"First off, you should never custom-flag opinion-based questions."* - You should never custom-flag opinion-based questions _just for being opinion-based_, there can certainly be other reasons to custom-flag them.